# Baby Rudin, Example 1.1, how?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A = \{p \in \mathbb{Q}^+ : p^2 \lt 2\} $ and $B = \{p \in \mathbb{Q}^+ : p^2 \gt 2\} $. We want to prove that $A$ has no maximum and $B $ has no minimum. I spent a good hour on this without being able to do it. This is how it was done in the book:

> Associate with every rational $p \gt 0$ the number
>
> (3) $$q=p- \frac{p^2-2}{p+2}$$
>
> Then
>
> (4) $$q^2-2 = \frac{2 (p^2-2)}{(p+2)^2} $$
>
> If $p $ is in $A $ then $p^2-2 \lt 0$, (3) shows that $q \gt p $, and (4) shows that $q^2 \lt 2$. Thus q is in $A $.  (and analogous for $B $).

Ok I can see it works. But how did he find that $q $? Why divide $p^2-2$ by $p+2$ and then subtract it to $p $? What process does one go to find the expressions that work?

Comment: I think this example exhibits a common criticism of Rudin: the proofs, while correct, contain very little insight. That is, it shows you a very slick proof but leaves you little to no clue how it got there. (However, I do hope someone here can help motivate Rudin’s proof!)